# Fit the width of the view to longest item of the QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a `QComboBox` which contains long strings. Long means that the strings are wider than the width of `QComboBox` on my `GUI`. In this case `Qt` will display the items in this way:

[image: QComboBox]

Previously I was working with `MatLab` which has a less user friendly `GUI` but for a drop-down list I think that the `MatLab` solution is better:

[image: MatLab drop-down list]

Is there any easy way to achieve a similar result in `Qt` or do I have to setup a custom model and view for this purpose ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done that few years back. Should be working fine.

```
//determinge the maximum width required to display all names in full
int max_width = 0;
QFontMetrics fm(ui.comboBoxNames->font());
for(int x = 0; x < NamesList.size(); ++x)
{
    int width = fm.width(NamesList[x]);
    if(width > max_width)
        max_width = width;
}
if(ui.comboBoxNames->view()->minimumWidth() < max_width)
{
    // add scrollbar width and margin
    max_width += ui.comboBoxNames->style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_ScrollBarExtent);
    max_width += ui.comboBoxNames->view()->autoScrollMargin();
    // set the minimum width of the combobox drop down list
    ui.comboBoxNames->view()->setMinimumWidth(max_width);
}
```

Comment: works fine when replacing NamesList with ui.comboBoxNames->itemText .